# Parsing ChildNodes of ChildNodes

Tags: xml, vba

I want to extract data from XML files to Excel spreadsheets in VBA.

All the XML files have the same format :

```
<Suite>
    <Writer>John Doe</Writer>
    <Reviewer>John Die</Reviewer>
    <Status>Being reviwed</Status>
    <Cases>
        <Case>
            <Title>Case 1</Title>
            <Id>1<id>
            <Steps>
                <Step>
                    <Description>This is step 1</Description>
                </Step>
                <Step>
                    <Description>This is step 2</Description>
                </Step>
            </Steps>
        </Case>
        <Case>
            <Title>Case 1</Title>
            <Id>1<id>
            <Steps>
                <Step>
                    <Description>This is step 1</Description>
                </Step>
                <Step>
                    <Description>This is step 2</Description>
                </Step>
            </Steps>
        <Case>
    </Cases>
</Suite>
```

There are more cases and more steps in each case.

The code I have extracts the single nodes of the first level of ChildNode. Example extracting the Title of each Case.

I would like to extract the Description of every step, in every case.

```vb
Public Sub ExecBlockXMLExtract(ByRef BlockDescription, Optional MyItem As Variant)
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim CurrentRow As Integer
    
    Dim XMLFile        As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim XMLChildNodeL1 As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim XMLNode        As IXMLDOMNode
    
    Set XMLFile = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    XMLFile.Load FullPathfile
    If bChildNodesL1 Then
        Set XMLChildNodeL1 = XMLFile.SelectSingleNode(ChildNodePathL1).ChildNodes
    End If

    For Each XMLNode In XMLChildNodeL1
        For i = 1 To nbColumnsL1
        'This block extracts the singlenodes of the L1 ChildNode
            If UCase(ListColumns(i, 3)) = "PROPERTY" Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Cells(CurrentRow, i).Value = CallByName(XMLFile, ListColumns(i, 2), VbGet)
                On Error GoTo 0
            Else
                Cells(CurrentRow, i).Value = XMLNode.SelectSingleNode(ListColumns(i, 2)).Text
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        For i = 1 To nbColumns
            If UCase(ListColumns(i, 3)) = "PROPERTY" Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Cells(CurrentRow, i).Value = CallByName(XMLFile, ListColumns(i, 2), VbGet)
                On Error GoTo 0
            Else
                Cells(CurrentRow, i).Value = XMLFile.SelectSingleNode(ListColumns(i, 2)).Text
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    
End Sub
```

I'm struggling to select a childnode "Steps" when I'm already in a childnode "Cases".

I'm used to C or Python.

Here is the code I modified :

```
        For Each XMLNode In XMLChildNodeL1
            For i = 1 To nbColumnsL1
            'This block extracts the singlenodes of the L1 ChildNode
                If UCase(ListColumns(i, 3)) = "PROPERTY" Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Cells(CurrentRow, i).Value = CallByName(XMLFile, ListColumns(i, 2), VbGet)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                Else
                    Cells(CurrentRow, i).Value = XMLNode.SelectSingleNode(ListColumns(i, 2)).Text
                End If
            Next i
            If bChildNodesL2 Then
                XMLChildNodeL2 = XMLNode.SelectNodes(ChildNodePathL2)
            End If
            CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
        Next
```

The issue is that `XMLNode` is already a IXMLDOMNode Object set to Suite/Cases/Case[i] node. And the 'XMLNode.SelectNodes(ChildNodePathL2)' doesn't work because XMLNode don't have a `SelectNodes` methods.

How can I select the second level of childnodes?

Comment: Please update your post to add your existing code, and explain the exact problem you have when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few errors in your posted XML but after fixing those this worked for me:

```vb
Sub Tester2()
    
    Dim oDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim els As Object, el As Object, steps As Object, stp As Object
    
    oDoc.validateOnParse = True
    oDoc.LoadXML Sheet2.Range("A1").Value 'load XML from cell
    
    Debug.Print oDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Suite/Writer").Text
    Debug.Print oDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Suite/Reviewer").Text
    Debug.Print oDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Suite/Status").Text
    
    Set els = oDoc.SelectNodes("//Suite/Cases/Case") 'get cases
    If els.Length > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Found  - " & els.Length & " cases"
        Debug.Print "----------------------"
        For Each el In els
            Debug.Print el.SelectSingleNode("Title").Text
            Debug.Print el.SelectSingleNode("id").Text
            Set steps = el.SelectNodes("Steps/Step") 'get case steps
            For Each stp In steps
                Debug.Print , stp.SelectSingleNode("Description").Text
            Next stp
            
        Next el
    End If
    
End Sub
```

XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Suite>
    <Writer>John Doe</Writer>
    <Reviewer>John Die</Reviewer>
    <Status>Being reviwed</Status>
    <Cases>
        <Case>
            <Title>Case 1</Title>
            <id>1</id>
            <Steps>
                <Step><Description>This is step 1</Description></Step>
                <Step><Description>This is step 2</Description></Step>
            </Steps>
        </Case>
        <Case>
            <Title>Case 2</Title>
            <id>2</id>
            <Steps>
                <Step><Description>This is step 1</Description></Step>
                <Step><Description>This is step 2</Description></Step>
            </Steps>
        </Case>
    </Cases>
</Suite>
```

Comment: Hi Tim ! I've just tried it and include it in my existing code and it's working properly ! I don't know why the previous guy used `XMLFile.SelectSingleNode(ChildNodePathL1).ChildNodes` but it's now working ! Thanks a lot !